# Allegro5 Problems with deleting a text and display a new one after pressing a button

Tags: c++, allegro5

So I wrote this code where if I press enter it should clear the page and then enter a new text that says "game starts". but it won't run at all and just stays the same, anyone knows how to fix this?

PS. Extra question, how do I create a delay after replacing the text for 5 seconds then clear the text again?

Thank!

```
#include <iostream>
#include<allegro5/allegro.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_font.h>

#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>


int main()
{
    al_init();
    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display = al_create_display(640, 480);
    ALLEGRO_FONT* font = al_load_ttf_font("YARDSALE.ttf", 30, 0);
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE* queue = al_create_event_queue();

    al_install_keyboard();
    al_install_mouse();

    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_mouse_event_source());
    bool done = false;

    while (!done) {
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
        al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(139, 0, 0), 320, 150, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTER, "Press Enter to start");
        al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(148, 0, 211), 320, 300, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTER, "PRESS ESC TO QUIT");
        al_flip_display();

        ALLEGRO_EVENT event;
        al_wait_for_event(queue, &event);

        if (event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP)
        {
            switch (event.keyboard.keycode)
            {
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                done = true;
                break;
            case ALLEGRO_KEY_ENTER:

                al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
                al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 300, 200, 0, "Game Starts");
                al_flip_display;

                break;

            }
        }
    }
    al_destroy_font(font);
    al_destroy_display(display);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply missed "()" when you called 'al_flip_display'. It should be 'al_flip_display();'.
But even with this it will not work as expected, because "Game starts" will only appears for a moment. I suggest adding game states.
And I think at the end of the main function you should also destroy event queue.

```
#include<allegro5/allegro.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_font.h>

#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>

enum class GAME_STATE { CLICK, INTRO, MAIN };

int main()
{
    al_init();
    al_init_font_addon();
    al_init_ttf_addon();

    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display = al_create_display(640, 480);
    ALLEGRO_FONT* font = al_load_ttf_font("font_code_pro.ttf", 30, 0);
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE* queue = al_create_event_queue();
    ALLEGRO_TIMER* timer = al_create_timer(1 / 60.0);

    al_install_keyboard();
    al_install_mouse();

    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_mouse_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(queue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
    bool done = false;
    bool draw = false;

    unsigned delay = 0;

    GAME_STATE state = GAME_STATE::CLICK;

    al_start_timer(timer);

    while(!done)
    {
        ALLEGRO_EVENT event;
        al_wait_for_event(queue, &event);

        if(event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER)
        {
            draw = true;

            if(state == GAME_STATE::INTRO && !((++delay) % (60 * 5)))state = GAME_STATE::MAIN;
        }

        if(event.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN)
        {
            switch(event.keyboard.keycode)
            {
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_ESCAPE:
                    done = true;
                    break;
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_ENTER:
                    if(state == GAME_STATE::CLICK)
                        state = GAME_STATE::INTRO;
                    break;

            }
        }

        if(draw)
        {
            draw = false;
            switch(state)
            {
                case GAME_STATE::CLICK:
                    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
                    al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(139, 0, 0), 320, 150, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTER, "Press Enter to start");
                    al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(148, 0, 211), 320, 300, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTER, "PRESS ESC TO QUIT");
                    al_flip_display();
                    break;
                case GAME_STATE::INTRO:
                    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
                    al_draw_text(font, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 300, 200, 0, "Game Starts");
                    al_flip_display();
                    break;
                case GAME_STATE::MAIN:
                    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255));
                    //
                    al_flip_display();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    al_destroy_font(font);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    al_destroy_event_queue(queue);
    al_destroy_display(display);
}
```

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm currently trying out Allegro for making some simple games and it is really hard to find sources or guides for it because it is really old. Wonder if it might be too troublesome if I get in contact with you for some guidance? Maybe even other than allegro. Hope to hear from you!

Comment: I started learning Allegro about year or two years ago. I highly recommend http://fixbyproximity.com/2d-game-development-course/ and http://fixbyproximity.com/oop-game-development/. I've watched both. They are fantastic! When it comes to guidance I will help you with pleasure. We can learn together! Any idea how or where we can communicate?

Comment: That would be awesome! Do you have any platform of preference? You can pick and i'll follow. Also i am actually currently using that for game development study!